# Where can I get advice on how to build completely ajax web apps?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, web-applications

I am building a completely ajax web app (this is the first web app I have ever created). I am not exactly sure if I am going about it the right way. Any suggestions or places where I can go to find suggestions?

Update:

I currently am using jQuery. I am working on fully learning that. I have designed a UI almost completely. I am struggling in some parts trying to balance a good UX, good design and fitting all the options I want to fit in it.

I have started with the design. I am currently struggling with whether to use absolute positioning or not and if not how do I use float etc. to do the same type of thing. I am trying to make it have a liquid layout (I hate fixed-layout pages) and am trying to figure out what I should use to make it look the same in most screen sizes.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Tell us what you're trying to do and we'll suggest what might be the "right way".

Comment: @casablanca ok, I just updated the question.

Comment: maybe you can split the CSS question and the server programming language into two other separate questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Understand JavaScript.** Know what a closure is, how JavaScript's event handling works, how JavaScript interacts with the DOM (beyond simply using jQuery), prototypal inheritance, and other things. It will help you when your code doesn't work and you need to fix it.
2. **Maintain usability.** All the AJAX magic you add is useless if users cannot figure out how to use it. Keep things simple, don't overload the user by giving him information he doesn't need to know (hide less important information, allowing the user to click a link to show it), and if possible, test your app with actual users to make sure that the interface is intuitive to them.
3. **Code securely.** Do not allow your server to get hacked. There are many different [types of security flaws](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) in web apps, including cross-site scripting (XSS), cross-site request forgery (CSRF), and SQL injection. You need to be well aware of these and other pitfalls and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

One starting point is to look at the Javascript Libraries and decide which one to use:

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

You probably don't want to do raw Javascript code without any library.  Once you decide on a library to use, then you can look at its documentations online or the books about using them.  jQuery does have pretty good documentation.

Comment: Then there are many good books on jQuery.  One of them is JQUERY: NOVICE TO NINJA http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/  there is a sample PDF there.  jQuery Cookbook is quite good too: http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Cookbook-Solutions-Examples-Developers/dp/0596159773

Answer (score 1):

Define "right way."
There are many "right ways" to code an app.

Things to keep in mind are trying to design a nice interface. The interface can make or break an application and studies show that it can even make it seem faster if you do it right. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is good for this.

Another thing to consider going in is what browsers do you want to support? Firefox is really doing well and Google Chrome's market share is growing so you will want so support those for sure. IE is a tough one as it doesn't have the best support for standards, but if you are selling a product you will really want this.

Comment: ok, thanks, I am definitely working heavily on the interface. That one is very important to me. I am having some difficulties with the CSS because I am trying to create an app with a liquid layout. I have difficulties desiding whether I should use absolute positioning for things or not. Any thoughts on this? Any resources that would help me with this? I am definitely planning to support chrome, firefox and ie8+. I am still deciding if I will be able to do what I want to and still support ie7. There is very little chance I will support ie6.

Comment: A liquid layout generally would not include absolute positioning. You would be more likely to use relative positioning to move it from where it stands without the positioning.

Comment: @AJ00200 ok, interesting. So... I was thinking of using javascript to detect the browser size and reposition the elements. I am assuming this would make it very strange?

Comment: @chromedude this is generally discouraged, even more so since some people disable Javascript. It is best to stick with pure CSS and (X)HTML when creating layouts and then use the float attribute to create columns, use % to set the amount of the available space to take up and so on.

Comment: @AJ00200 ok, I see what your saying. Well, if they don't have javascript enabled they won't be able to use my app because everything of value in it is manipulated by javascript. Do you have any suggestions on resources I could look at for that type of positioning? I read a book on CSS, but usually my layouts become all weird.

Comment: @chromedude This article explains it all very well: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

Answer (score 1):

One of the best articles that I've ever come across about the *structure* of an ajax web application is [this one](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/build-your-own-ajax-web-apps). A little outdated because it refers to XML as the primary data-interchange format, now [JSON](http://json.org/). [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a javascript framework, contains excellent functionality for both DOM manipulation and AJAX calls. Both are a must in any AJAX-driven web app.